# Comparing two arrays of objects if one property is also an array in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter

I have two arrays:
First - jobs array of objects that contains array itemIds, like this:

```js
jobs: [{
        name: null
        id: 612
        items: []
        stat: 1
        itemIds: [223, 1234]
    },
    {
        name: null
        id: 734
        items: []
        stat: 2
        itemIds: [564]
    }
    .
    .
    .
]
```

and second array - items, like this:

```js
items: [{
        act: true
        id: 1234
        name: "Item1"
    },
    {
        act: true
        id: 222
        name: "Item2"
    },
]
```

How to filter out an array of items whos id isn't equal to any of itemIds from jobs array or that property stat from jobs array isn't equal to 0 ?
I tried with three loops, but it dropped out only one item with the same id in a array of jobs.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We are going to use `Array.filter` to loop over every elements in `items` and create a new array containing only the items you want to keep.

For each of the values, we are going to see if any job contains in `itemIds` the code `id`. To do that, we are going to loop over every job and for every job, we are going to look at the underlying `ItemsIds` values.

`Array.some` here will leave as soon at it find something.

```js
const jobs = [{
    name: null,
    id: 612,
    items: [],
    stat: 1,
    itemIds: [223, 1234],
  },
  {
    name: null,
    id: 612,
    items: [],
    stat: 2,
    itemIds: [223, 1234],
  },
  {
    name: null,
    id: 734,
    items: [],
    stat: 2,
    itemIds: [564],
  }
];

const items = [{
    act: true,
    id: 1234,
    name: 'Item1',
  },
  {
    act: true,
    id: 222,
    name: 'Item2',
  },
];

const filteredItems = items.filter(x => jobs.some(y => y.itemIds.includes(x.id) && y.stat !== 1));

console.log(filteredItems);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, You saved my day ! And if I want to add one more condition, like that stat in array jobs isnt equal to 1, I'll do that like this:   const filteredItems = items.filter(x => jobs.some(y => y.itemIds.includes(x.id || y.stat !== 1))) ?

Comment: You should insert the additional conditions after the `.includes()` method. I've edited my snippet with your `stat` example. Good luck